# Expected number of steps to get "ABRACADABRA"

Tags: probability, expected-value, martingales, stopping-times

Suppose you have a 26-sided die, each face is labelled from A-Z, what is the expected number of steps to observe the sequence "ABRACADABRA" for the first time?

ANS = $26^{11} + 26^4 + 26$

A common technique to handle these kind of problems is to draw a markov chain and state which correspond to observing the pattern "ABRACADABRA" is marked absorbing then you calculate expected number of steps till absorption, but I think this method is tedious (especially for the given sequence) and I believe there is some technique related to *Optional Stopping Theorem* that could be applied here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931839/expected-number-of-output-letters-to-get-desired-word) for a discussion of Conway's method for solving such problems.

Comment: An aproach using generating functions is shown here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961805/non-martingale-approach-to-abracadabra-problem/2962758#2962758